# Passing Object of Entity column to a method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method in the class which i have written below:-

```
 public void Insert<EntityColumn>(int foreignKeyId, EntityColumn column,
        TList<xyz> entity, TransactionManager transactionManager)
{
    entity.ForEach (
                 pca =>
                 {
                     pca.GetType().GetProperty(column.ToString()).SetValue(pca, foreignKeyId, null);
                     pca.EntityState = EntityState.Added;
                     _provider.payment.Insert(transactionManager, pca);
                 }
            );
}
```

Now i want to call this method from the test class. In place of the EntityColumn column , i want to send the column name of the object.  Object here is the representation of my table. Table name is ClientData. Say Column is "InvoiceNo".  So how  can set this and pass to this method. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my developer tools at the moment, so can't test this first. But I think if you change to this it will function as written in your example.

```
public void Insert<TableType>(int foreignKeyId, string columnName,
    TList<TableType> entity, TransactionManager transactionManager) {

    entity.ForEach(pca => {
        pca.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).SetValue(pca, foreignKeyId, null);
        pca.EntityState = EntityState.Added;
        _provider.payment.Insert(transactionManager, pca);
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but you'll notice that you're only using the column variable as a string to represent the name of the property you want to invoke off of the type represented by TableType. I never saw a place where you needed to know the type of column, but maybe I'm not seeing the bigger picture.

Since you told it the type of your entity TList you shouldn't have to use reflection at all though and I'll admit I still don't get what you are trying to do.